# Webpack "start": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js", not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am learning react and Webpack dev server is not starting and giving me this error

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'

Scripts

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js",
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config=config/webpack.prod.js",
"compile": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
```

},

Terminal output

```
 npm start
```

> react-shopping-cart@0.1.0 start C:\Users\iClick Digital\                                                                             Documents\ZerotoMastery\frontendprojects\react-shopping-ca                                                                             rt
>   webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/                                                                             cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.                                                                             js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:                                                                             17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object. (C:\Users\iClick Digital\Documen                                                                             ts\ZerotoMastery\frontendprojects\react-shopping-cart\conf                                                                             ig\webpack.dev.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678                                                                             :30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs                                                                             /loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:1                                                                             2)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.                                                                             js:520:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-shopping-cart@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-ser                                                                             ver --config=config/webpack.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-shopping-cart@0.1.0 start scr                                                                             ipt.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is                                                                              likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missi                                                                             ng, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\iClick Digital\AppData\Roaming\npm-c                                                                             ache_logs\2018-09-02T12_06_07_432Z-debug.log

Comment: Maybe you forgot to run `npm iinstall` ? Show your full `package.json` and webpack config file.

Comment: Hi Karen , I installed webpack globally as it was first installed locally and now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

you need to install all dependencies from your package.json by running this command:

```
npm i
```

later you can run all of your scripts like this:

```
npm run start
```

I hope this would be helpful

Comment: Hi Sakhi, do I need to install all dependencies myself in terminal when I clone repo from GitHub or they already installed ?

Comment: No we don’t push node_modules in repository. That’s why we have package json. Node modules take large disk storage. We download dependencies locally